# How can PowerShell scripts automate tasks and send email in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-data-factory

To capture pipeline activity failed errors and send email notifications to users using PowerShell in Azure Data Factory without using Logic App or other custom activities

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately ADF as is doesnt have any direct native feature to send custom email aspects and doesnt have a direct platform to execute powershell queries.

You would need to integrate it with some other Azure offerings like Azure Automation, Azure function or logic app etc.

You can create alerts on pipelines on failures which would send email to the users but it wont contain all proper custom details as per your needs